# Careers 2.0: Account linking problem

Tags: support, jobs, openid, login

Something screwy is afoot.  I recently got my invitation to Careers.  Happy, I raced to the site to fill out my profile.  Somehow I seem to have two accounts on there (one is linked to my regular StackExchange account, and the other seems to be a newly created or funky linked account.  I am using both my gmail account and my OpenID.com to authenticate.

## Account 1:

- Original StackExchange Account
- Uses OpenID and a Google Account (Not GMail) but is defunct

## Account 2:

- New account that apparently got created when I used my GMail (!!! should have known better) account after clicking the invitation link
- Uses GMail
- Has fledgling profile filled out

## What happens

When logged into Account 1, I remove the OpenID auth.  Logout...

Logged into Account 2, I go to Add OpenID, and attempt to add my OpenID.  It appears to work!  But upon clicking on Profile, I get the "Request an invite" page, and I click on my name and find that I have been silently signed into Account 1!    Also, my OpenID is once again attributed to Account 1.

Methinks I broke something when I accidentally used an OpenID that was not (currently) part of my SE profile.  I have since added it, but the damage is done.  Any help from an Admin?

Comment: Is this still an issue? I see one account for you with a fairly complete profile. If so, email me details for both accounts to careers at stackoverflow dot com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found both your accounts (thanks to your email) and have merged them. You should see your SO account on your careers profile now.

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue with my Careers account. Are you able to resolve that as well @Korneel? My apologies if this is not the appropriate channel for these types of requests. Please let me know if you need additional info or if there is a better place for this type of support request.

Comment: @Colin Can you email me at careers at stackoverflow dot com with your account information? Thanks!